# How to delete database item with rowindex

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm trying to delete a row from datagrid and database by it's index number in datagrid but I don't know how to write my syntax.

I have searched and changed my code a lot but I couldn't find it I would be thankful for your help.

the code should look like ::

```
string query = "Delete from Table1 where RowIndex = 5;
```

but it's wrong.  How should I change this code?

I don't want to add rowindex into my database fields.  I mean I want to delete the row by the order of them in datagrid.

Comment: You can't do that in the general case. Hopefully your table has a primary key, you need to have that primary key associated with your row even if you don't display it in your datagrid. Then you delete rows by their primary key, usually referred to as the id.

Comment: thanks for answering fast!!  is this movie fine for what i want to do :::   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhCNGCaJ4-Y

Comment: I mean i need more info